# Distributing PC software without a website

Tags: software-distribution

I am trying to distribute a small PC program, but have run into a few problems. I first tried to upload it to cNet, and then to softonic, but the problem with these sites, and all that I have seen like them is that they require a direct link(which I can't get, see below).

After running into that problem, I simply uploaded my software to a file sharing site, but in reality, very few of my current users(from a mobile version)installed my software because once downloaded was listed as dangerous by the anti-virus due to the website that it was downloaded from.

So then I set about trying to find a download website that would give me a direct link, but unsurprisingly, I can't find that. I can't host the file myself, because I don't have a webpage.

Even though I haven't found any, I would be fine with a site that hosts my software and doesn't require a direct download link to use.  Or I would be fine with a site that would give me a direct download link.

I'm interested in an answer to the general problem - distributing software without a website.  I assume that not everyone who has ever released software has their own webpage, what is the best way to get around this?

Comment: If you're trying to distribute an executable, most anti-virus programs will flag it as questionable if they don't have a record of many people downloading the file. That doesn't matter which site you use. Can't you just create a blog on something like Tumblr for free and provide the file there?

Comment: And the reason you can't set up your own web page is....?  If for no other reason, it'll give you a place to describe the program in detail so people know what they are downloading.

Comment: If you're asking us to recommend a website that will host your software, then the question is off topic.

Comment: You can add it to the Windows 8 store

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's an open source project intended for developers, GitHub or Codeplex are good places to host your product with the ability to download it.

If it's a library, then most ecosystems have some sort of package managers. For example, Node.js has [npm](https://npmjs.org/), and .NET Framework has NuGet.

If it's a software application intended for end users, then create a website; there are plenty of companies which provide free or extremely cheap hosting. I can see several benefits in having your own website:

- It's hugely extensive.

  One day, you want to add a feedback feature? You can do it. Later, you want to publish your source code? You can. Later, you want to track your visitors? No problem. Want to add a YouTube video presenting the product? Do it.

  If you stick with any service which does some of those features for you, one day you'll need just another fancy feature the service won't provide.
- It's a way to do marketing.

  Just a download link? Well, what if I want to discover a bit more about your software and you before downloading it? I don't want my PC be filled by crap written by Mister Anonymous. Knowing that a given person have written the app, seing the screenshots, seeing the video which shows the lead developer explaining why the software is so great would convince me much more.
- It's a way to learn.

  You're not a web developer, right? Otherwise, probably, you wouldn't have asked this question. Then creating your own website may teach you new things which are damn useful for any developer nowadays. I'm not saying that everyone should know HTML and CSS and SQL and JavaScript, but discovering all those technologies and languages won't hurt anybody.

Comment: The project is not open-source. I guess the best option really is to buckle down and figure websites out. I was kind of hoping that there might be a site that would my software.... Anyways, thanks for the advice, and as the only answer thus far, I'll accept it.